# How can I show notification message after redirect a page in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've searched for this problem a lot. But I couldn't find any solve. Please help me.

I want to redirect a page in middleware. And then showing notification (with vue-notification). I can to that when page loaded. But if the user tries to get that page in URL, I want to redirect again. But still showing notification message. :)

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and here is my workaround.

On the middleware file, return redirect to the desired page then add an optional query parameter that you would check against on the desired page when it loads. then on conditional check against that query parameter, you pop up a notification. You can use [noty plugin](https://github.com/renoguyon/vuejs-noty) to display the notification.

So in summary...

```
//In middleware file
return('/to/desired/page?queryName=queryValue')

//In Desired Page file
<script>
...
mounted(){
   if(this.$route.query.queryName == queryValue){
     
    this.$noty.error('your notification message here')
    // or .info  or .warning ...check the link for more
  }
}
...
</script>
```